# Using regexp_extract() to extract phone numbers from call logs

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table with a column `Col1` containing a string in this format:

`sip: 3334445678 @ 10.10.0.134`

Now, I want to extract just the phone number part using:

`SELECT regexp_extract(Col1,'\D{10}',0) FROM Table;`

In my understanding, `\D{10}` looks for a pattern of ten consecutive digits. However, when I run the script, I get nulls and empty rows. What am I missing here?

Also, I do need to use pattern matching, because some records display the phone number only; this leaves out `substr` as a potential option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
select regexp_extract('3334445678 @ 10.10.0.134', '[0-9]{10}',0) from table limit 1;
3334445678
```

I'm not sure why the syntax you used is not working. Might be because Hive's RE engine doesn't support PCRE.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks! I'd vote you up, but I apparently can't until I get 15 points.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select regexp_extract('3334445678 @ 10.10.0.134','\\d{10}',0) from test limit 1;
```